# PostgreSQL: adding a few columns more than triples the original table size

Tags: postgresql

I created a `table2` from another `table1` with:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1;
```

`table1` is 4.8 GB with 1.5 mio. rows and 20 columns of types integer (8x), charvar(1) (9x), real (2x) and geometry (1x). `table2` is 3.5 GB after doing that.

I then add 3 columns (real, real, integer) to `table2`, and update the columns with some values.

However, after doing that, `table2` becomes about 4 times larger with 14 GB.

What could be the cause for that? I expect adding these columns would occupy less space.

I performed a full vacuum but it didn't change anything.

I check the sizes with:

```
select table_name, pg_total_relation_size(quote_ident(table_name))
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
order by 2;
```

I create the table and use the update-set commands in a SQL script called with psql:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
...
All my SQL commands
...
END $$
```

Comment: Do you know if it is the DDL or the DML that increases its size?

Comment: The size increases a lot after the update-set commands, so it's the DML... The table size doubles after using an "UPDATE table2 SET my_field_integer = CASE...", and then doubles again using 4 different "SET my_field_real = ROUND(CAST(field_a / (field_b * 0.27777) AS numeric), 1)"...

Comment: What is a "full vacuum"?  Is that the same thing as VACUUM FULL?  Or does that just mean you didn't interrupt it half way through?

Comment: Yes, I meant a vacuum full, following the advice here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172247/postgresql-table-size-growth-after-adding-column

Comment: I can't replicate this at all.  How do you even get 1.5M rows to take up 3.5Go in the first place?   It is not easy to do that even through malice.

Comment: Can you get the sizes separately for main table, toast table, and indexes?  Also what version are you using?

Comment: @jjanes The table contains the whole road network of France. The geometry column counts for about half the size. I use PostgreSQL 12.3.1 on Linux with the PostGIS extension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is as expected. Since updating a row will write a new row version while leaving the old one in place, updating all rows of a table will double its size.

If you run several updates without giving autovacuum time in between to free the dead row version, the size can increase even more.

After your updates are done, run `VACUUM (FULL)` on the table to rewrite it and get rid of the extra storage space.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I better understand how it works now.

Answer (score 1):

In stead of adding and updating the columns when table2 has been created, add the new columns to the select when you create table2.

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
  SELECT t1.*,
    ... new_real1,
    ... new_real2,
    ... new_int
  FROM table1 t1;
```